# Find website UA-ID

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to operate a Google analytics account which has now been locked out of due to the previous operator leaving the company. So I am unable to log in. I know the email, but not the password. I've searched ways to find the UA-ID , and apparently I'm supposed to look inside the `<head>` of my site's homepage. However I can't find anything there that looks like it is the UA-ID. Reason I need the UA-ID is so I can [verify my site to google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7268497#prove), so I can login to it. Can somebody give me some direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) or the [Google Analytics Debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) in Chrome, both will give you detailed information on your GA implementation (for the debugger you have to open the browser console).

Or simply go to the browser console, look at the network tab and search for a request to google-analytics.com/collect (or stats.doubleclick.com/collect if you have enabled demographic features in GA), and search the parameters for the tracking id (starts with "UA-").